# Initialize multidimensional array in plpgsql

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

can someone tell me how to initialize a multidimensional array in plpgsql? Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo() 
RETURNS text[]
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$$
DECLARE
    var text[][];
BEGIN
    var := array[['1', 'a'],['2', 'b']];
    RETURN var;
END;
$$;
```

Test:

```
SELECT foo();
```

Comment: Can this be done as the DEFAULT during the DECLARE section.  (e.g. `DECLARE    var TEXT[][] := array[['1', 'a'],['2','b']];`)

Answer (score 1):

```
pavel=# select array_fill(0, ARRAY[2,2]);
  array_fill   
───────────────
 {{0,0},{0,0}}
(1 row)

pavel=# select array_fill('a'::text, ARRAY[2,2,2]);
          array_fill           
───────────────────────────────
 {{{a,a},{a,a}},{{a,a},{a,a}}}
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 0):

post in relation : [PostgreSQL: ERROR: array subscript out of range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59770157/postgresql-error-array-subscript-out-of-range)

Example:
DO $$
declare
aa integer[][];
begin
aa := array_fill(0, array[5,3]);
raise notice 'aa: %', aa;
for c1 in 1..5 loop
for c2 in 2..3 loop
aa[c1][c2] :=  c1*c2;
end loop;
end loop;
raise notice 'aa: %', aa;
end; $$