# PostgreSQL: ERROR: array subscript out of range

Tags: arrays, postgresql, loops

I am trying to fill two dimensional array

```
do $$

declare pole text[][];

begin
for y in 1..6
loop
  for x in 1..4
  loop
    pole[y][x] = '0';
    raise notice 'x: %',x;
    raise notice 'y: %',y;
  end loop;
end loop;

/*
pole  := '{
{0,0,0,0}, 
{7,0,0,0},
{0,0,0,0},
{0,0,0,0},
{0,0,0,0}
}';
*/

raise notice 'pole : %', pole;
raise notice 'pole one: %', pole[2][1];

end $$
```

but getting `ERROR: array subscript out of range`, If I fill the array manually like pole[6][4] := '0' it has no problem, but once the loop is used I get error, I don't know why, variables are between 1 and 4 and 1 and 6 and manual assignment works. This is basic programming am I missing something?

```
1) SQL State: 00000 --- x: 1
2) SQL State: 00000 --- y: 1
3) SQL State: 00000 --- x: 2
4) SQL State: 00000 --- y: 1
5) SQL State: 00000 --- x: 3
6) SQL State: 00000 --- y: 1
7) SQL State: 00000 --- x: 4
8) SQL State: 00000 --- y: 1
9) SQL State: 00000 --- x: 1
10) SQL State: 00000 --- y: 2
11) SQL State: 00000 --- x: 2
12) SQL State: 00000 --- y: 2
13) SQL State: 00000 --- x: 3
14) SQL State: 00000 --- y: 2
15) SQL State: 00000 --- x: 4
16) SQL State: 00000 --- y: 2
17) SQL State: 00000 --- x: 1
18) SQL State: 00000 --- y: 3
19) SQL State: 00000 --- x: 2
20) SQL State: 00000 --- y: 3
21) SQL State: 00000 --- x: 3
22) SQL State: 00000 --- y: 3
23) SQL State: 00000 --- x: 4
24) SQL State: 00000 --- y: 3
25) SQL State: 00000 --- x: 1
26) SQL State: 00000 --- y: 4
27) SQL State: 00000 --- x: 2
28) SQL State: 00000 --- y: 4
29) SQL State: 00000 --- x: 3
30) SQL State: 00000 --- y: 4
31) SQL State: 00000 --- x: 4
32) SQL State: 00000 --- y: 4
33) SQL State: 00000 --- x: 1
34) SQL State: 00000 --- y: 5
35) SQL State: 00000 --- x: 2
36) SQL State: 00000 --- y: 5
37) SQL State: 00000 --- x: 3
38) SQL State: 00000 --- y: 5
39) SQL State: 00000 --- x: 4
40) SQL State: 00000 --- y: 5
41) SQL State: 00000 --- x: 1
42) SQL State: 00000 --- y: 6
43) SQL State: 00000 --- x: 2
44) SQL State: 00000 --- y: 6
45) SQL State: 00000 --- x: 3
46) SQL State: 00000 --- y: 6
47) SQL State: 00000 --- x: 4
48) SQL State: 00000 --- y: 6
```

> PostgreSQL 11.6 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.5
>   20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39), 64-bit

Comment: can you try `for y in 1..array_length(pole,1) loop`?

Comment: yes, result was "[Code: 0, SQL State: 22004]  ERROR: upper bound of FOR loop cannot be null
  Kde: PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 6 at FOR with integer loop variable"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multidimensional array [cannot grow](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html#ARRAYS-MODIFYING) like 1D arrays

> A stored array value can be enlarged by assigning to elements not
>   already present. Any positions between those previously present and
>   the newly assigned elements will be filled with nulls. For example, if
>   array myarray currently has 4 elements, it will have six elements
>   after an update that assigns to myarray[6]; myarray[5] will contain
>   null. **Currently, enlargement in this fashion is only allowed for
>   one-dimensional arrays, not multidimensional arrays.**

So you would have to initialize the array first, then populate it.

```
do $$

declare pole text[][];

begin

pole := array_fill(null::text, array[6,4]);

for y in 1..6
loop
  for x in 1..4
  loop

    raise notice 'x: %',x;
    raise notice 'y: %',y;
    pole[y][x] = '0';
  end loop;
end loop;


raise notice 'pole : %', pole;
raise notice 'pole one: %', pole[2][1];

end $$;
```